# abandon a column, also $n$ different row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, vector-spaces, coding-theory

$A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, whose $n$ row vectors  are all different. then, we can get rid of one column  of $A$(there exist a column, we abandon this column ),  such that the new  $n\times (n-1)$ matrix $B$ also has $n$  different row vectors.

With Mathematical Induction, we can prove the statement. But, **Is any other methods**?

---

[Editor's note: Below is my interpretation of what the question is meant to be (based on the exchange of comments below), JL]

---

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with distinct rows show that we can select one of its columns in such a way that removing the said column yields an $n\times (n-1)$ matrix $B$ that still has distinct rows.

Apparently the OP knows of a way of proving this by induction, and is looking for a different approach.

Comment: "we can prove the judgment" And what is the judgement?

Comment: @5xum  My English is very bad, English is not my mother tongue, so Please don't be so serious with  this. anyway, this is a math forum

Comment: I'm sorry if you think I am mocking you. I am not. I am merely pointing out that your question is unclear: I do not know what you are trying to prove. That is why I am asking you what your judgement is.

Comment: @5xum We can get rid of a column of $A$, we get a matrix $B$. $B$ has $n$ different row vectors

Answer (score 1):

What you are saying is not true. For example, take the matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$ which has $2$ row vectors which are different. Now, get rid of the second column of $A$. Then the matrix $$B=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
which you get does not have $2$ different row vectors.

Comment: Your example is soooo much simpler than mine!

Comment: @amWhy It is, probably, the simplest example there is (except if replacing ones with zeroes and zeroes with ones is even simpler...).

Comment: oh. not every column.  there exist a column, abandon it

Comment: @ziangchen What kind of column exists? You will still hit a problem with the counterexample I provided...

Comment: @5xum as for your example, we must get rid of the first column of $A$. then $B=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: there exist a column of $A$, abandon  the column,  such that $B$ has $n$ different row vectors.

Comment: Yes, and what do you hope to prove with that? What you will be left with is one column of $A$ which is not composed of all equal numbers. What does that prove, other than the existence of such a column (which is much simpler to prove directly)?